# Laravel's polymorphic many-to-many is smarter than me

Tags: laravel, relationship

Good day.
For some time now I'm stuck in Laravel's relations and I'm not even sure what I'm duing anymore.
I don't know what is wrong, when accessing relation it return empty collection

**Location Model**

```
public $primaryKey = "alias";
    protected $keyType = "string";
    public $incrementing = false;
    public function resorses() 
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Resorse', "locationable"); 
    }
```

**Resorse Model**

```
public $primaryKey = "alias";
    protected $keyType = "string";
    public $incrementing = false;
    public function locations() 
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Location', "locationable"); 
    }
```

**Migration**

```
            $table->id();
            $table->string("location_alias");
            $table->string("locationable_type");
            $table->string("locationable_id");
            $table->timestamps();
      });
```

I do have a model and seeder for locationable for to simplify some of the stuff
**Seeder** creates data like this

```
                "locationable_type" => "App\Models\Resourse",
                "locationable_id" => "copper-ore",
```

Please save my soul

Comment: do you know how `Many To Many (Polymorphic)` works?

Comment: I guess no.  But i assume it must use IDs  and my problem is im using alia?